# How to stop an element to touch screen border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, screen, game-development

I am beginner to JS and I am trying to create a simple game in it. I am looking for a way to stop the player (20px x 20px) box causing the screen to scroll, i am looking for a fixed screen where the player cannot exceed the sides of the screen. Please see previous attempts below.

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="player"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
#player{
  border-radius: 30%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var player = document.getElementById("player")
var pros = {'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'speed': 10}
var ws = {'h': screen.height, 'w': screen.width}
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
  var keyP = event.key;
  if(keyP === "ArrowDown"){
    pros.top = pros.top + pros.speed;
  }else if(keyP === "ArrowUp"){
    pros.top = pros.top - pros.speed;
  }else if(keyP === "ArrowLeft"){
    pros.left = pros.left - pros.speed;
  }else if(keyP === "ArrowRight"){
    pros.left = pros.left + pros.speed;
  }
  if(pros.top < 0){
    pros.top = 0;
  }else if(pros.top > ws.h){
    pros.top = ws.h;
  }else if(pros.left < 0){
    pros.left = 0;
  }else if(pros.left > ws.w){
    pros.left = ws.w;
  }
  player.style.top = `${pros.top}px`;
  player.style.left = `${pros.left}px`;
});
```

Now, **I want the element to never escape the given screen area.** As you can see in the code that I have tried to use **screen.height/screen.width** to control it but still it escapes the area and the scroll bars get activated even in the full screen mode. It looks too messy for a game.

Here is picture of how it escapes the area:


In Full Screen Mode :
[image: Full Screen Mode]

Without Full Screen Mode :
[image: Without Full Screen]

Comment: You could create a <canvas> element instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most accurate position and dimensions measurements are available via the `getBoundingClientRect()` function.

So at the top of your keystroke callback I'd add two lines:

```
var screenRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
var playerRect = player.getBoundingClientRect();
```

These need to be calculated at every iteration in order to make sure that the "game" adapts to every screen change. Also any position increments are better calculated in percents of the screen size rather than static pixel values.

Your screen edge check should be rewritten like this:

```
if(playerRect.top < 0){
    pros.top = 0;
} else if(playerRect.top + playerRect.height > screenRect.height){
    // make sure the bottom edge of the player doesn't go over the bottom edge of the screen
    pros.top = screenRect.height - playerRect.height;
}

if(playerRect.left < 0){
    pros.left = 0;
} else if(playerRect.left + playerRect.width + > screenRect.width){
    // make sure the right edge of the player doesn't go over the right edge of the screen
    pros.left = screenRect.width - playerRect.width;
}
```

On the CSS side, try the following:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#player{
  border-radius: 30%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked pretty but i just had to mix your solution with @retr0 solution because we also have to minus the player height and width.

Answer (score 0):

The `height` and `width` of your PLAYER object is 20px as concluded from the Stylesheet that you have provided.

If you place your element on a 2D plane, then it's coordinates will be the point where its **TOP-LEFT** corner lie. Focus here.

So, your JavaScript should change to this:

```
  ...
  if(pros.top < 0){
    pros.top = 0;
  }else if(pros.top > ws.h-20){ // changed here
    pros.top = ws.h-20; // try playing with the value here
  }else if(pros.left < 0){ 
    pros.left = 0;
  }else if(pros.left > ws.w-20){ //changed here
    pros.left = ws.w-20; // try playing with the value here
  }
  ...
```

This would always place the `#player` element 20px inside on the horizntal axis and 20px on the vertical axis. I was successful in limiting the appearance of the horizontal scroll-bar but the vertical vanished only for a value of `ws.h-40`.

[image: This was the position that I could make the scroll bars disappear. For <code>left: ws.w-20</code> and <code>top: ws.h-40</code>]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is not the full solution but it is a important part of solution.

Answer (score -1):

Hey :) Maybe this helps you:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
```

Setting the `overflow: hidden` will hide the scrollbar.

Comment: I am looking to stop player from escaping the area not just hiding the scroll bar!